# How we can add categories by script to the wordpress admin category?

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually, if i avoid manually entry of categories, and want to add category by coding.
How it  can be possible? Please suggest as i am new to wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , there is a function in wordpress wp_create_category() , even you can see parameters of this function in wordpress manual as the link is

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category

Thanks